# Group nodes together in Cytoscape.js

Tags: grouping, cytoscape.js

I am using [Cytoscape](https://js.cytoscape.org/) for network visualization.

I have found this [example](http://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/demo.html) of grouped nodes that you can expand and contract.

My question is, is it possible to highlight nodes and then **dynamically** add/remove them to a group on an ad-hoc basis?

I am yet to find an examples online of someone actually trying this and all the examples I have found like the aforementioned already have the groups predefined in the initial data load.

Comment: Your link for `example` is now dead. Perhaps you can find a current link or update the question. :)

Comment: Does the accepted answer really answer your question? If not then why the accept? Your comment, for me, clearly explains why the answer is not acceptable.

Comment: I would give this an upvote but the answer is not the answer I seek and was accepted. Your question seems to be what I seek but because this has an accepted answer it is really giving out bad information. Those not know might think this is how the problem is solved when it is not.

Comment: This YouTube video does what I seek using Cytoscape and not Cytoscape.js. [Grouping Nodes in Cytoscape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl8TQCKN93I) - However it does not show the code that did this and that is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [drag and drop extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-compound-drag-and-drop) of cytoscape.

Also, there is the [clipboard extension](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-clipboard), where you can select multiple elements via ctrl + mousedrag.

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'node:parent',
      style: {
        'label': ''
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: '.cdnd-grabbed-node',
      style: {
        'background-color': 'red'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: '.cdnd-drop-sibling',
      style: {
        'background-color': 'red'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: '.cdnd-drop-target',
      style: {
        'border-color': 'red',
        'border-style': 'dashed'
      }
    }
  ],
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'a'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'b'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'c'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'd',
          parent: 'p'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'p'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [

    ]
  }
});

var cdnd = cy.compoundDragAndDrop();
var removeEmptyParents = false;

var isParentOfOneChild = function(node) {
  return node.isParent() && node.children().length === 1;
};

var removeParent = function(parent) {
  parent.children().move({
    parent: null
  });
  parent.remove();
};

var removeParentsOfOneChild = function() {
  cy.nodes().filter(isParentOfOneChild).forEach(removeParent);
};

// custom handler to remove parents with only 1 child on drop
cy.on('cdndout', function(event, dropTarget) {
  if (removeEmptyParents && isParentOfOneChild(dropTarget)) {
    removeParent(dropTarget);
  }
});

// custom handler to remove parents with only 1 child (on remove of drop target or drop sibling)
cy.on('remove', function(event) {
  if (removeEmptyParents) {
    removeParentsOfOneChild();
  }
});

// toggle check handler
document.getElementById('remove-1ch-parents').addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeEmptyParents = !removeEmptyParents;

  if (removeEmptyParents) {
    removeParentsOfOneChild();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#options {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>cytoscape-compound-drag-and-drop demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-compound-drag-and-drop@1.0.0/cytoscape-compound-drag-and-drop.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-compound-drag-and-drop</h1>
  <div id="cy"></div>
  <div id="options">
    <input id="remove-1ch-parents" type="checkbox" value="false" />
    <label for="remove-1ch-parents">Remove parents with only one child</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

The question itself is not that clear requirenment-wise, so if there is still something unclear, please edit it to be more precise (and maybe your code so that we can use that as a base. THX

Comment: I have seen this example before but does not match what I need. What I want to do is highlight (select) specific nodes, and add them to a group that does not exist yet, is this possible? i.e. create a new group once nodes have been selected by the user.

Comment: Selection can be done by e.g assigning colors on click and then by using above code. But like I said, improve your question, add your current approach and maybe use my code as a basis. After that I can help you with your endavours :)

Comment: There is a [meta discussion about this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411683/an-answer-is-accepted-even-though-the-op-explicitly-states-that-it-isnt-what-th). @Ebikeneser could you confirm that this answer does work for you? There seems to be some confusion about your acceptance given your last comment stated that it wasn't what you need.